# Not able to match regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a string like `"5-2,5-12,15-27,5-22,50-3,5-100"`

I need a regular expression which matches all the occurrences like below: -

```
5-2
5-12
5-22
5-100
```

What will be the correct regex that matches all of them.

Comment: Isn't splitting with a comma enough? Are you limited to regex?

Comment: only those like in your output example, or all of them? if only those, what's the rule? 5's and even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below regex:

```
(?<!\d)5-\d{1,}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vC2tU4/2)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to well understand your needs, but, how about:

```
$str = "5-2,5-12,15-27,5-22,50-3,5-100";
preg_match_all('/\b5-\d+/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches)
```

or

```
preg_match_all('/\b\d-\d+/', $str, $matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5-2
            [1] => 5-12
            [2] => 5-22
            [3] => 5-100
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL1eC1/1)**

**`/(?<!\d)\d\-\d{1,3}/g`**

If understand correctly the first part of the pattern is one single digit `\d` therefore we need to exclude other number with a lookbehind `(?<!\d)` followed by a `-` and last seems to be a number up to 3 digits if you need more you can remove the 3 and it will also work so it is either  `\d{1,3}` or `\d{1,}`